# how to set delegates to some user accounts with a service account, in java, with gmail api?

Tags: gmail-api

I am trying to set delegates to users with the gmail api, and i get a 403 error : "Delegation denied for inbound.admin@mydomain.com"

First, in the developper console, I have created a service account with domain wide delegation => i have created a key file (prov-demo-picpus-sofiam-087d89bad40e.json in the code bellow)
Then I have given it the both scopes in google admin console : 
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic 
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing

Then, to list delegate(s) of the user "syl.guy@mydomain.com", my code looks like :

```java
public class TestGoogle {

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    static GoogleCredential addServiceAccountGoogleCredentialAndProxy(GoogleCredential credential, String user) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        GoogleCredential credentialModifed = (new GoogleCredential.Builder()).setTransport(credential.getTransport()).setJsonFactory(credential.getJsonFactory()).setServiceAccountId(credential.getServiceAccountId())
                .setServiceAccountScopes(credential.getServiceAccountScopes()).setServiceAccountPrivateKey(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId()).setServiceAccountUser(user).build();
        return credentialModifed;

   }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic");
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing");
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("./target/classes/prov-demo-picpus-sofiam-087d89bad40e.json"))
                .createScoped(scopes);
    GoogleCredential credential2 = addServiceAccountGoogleCredentialAndProxy(credential,"inbound.admin@mydomain.com");
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,credential2).setApplicationName("appli-testsg").build();

        Gmail.Users.Settings.Delegates.List request2 = gmail.users().settings().delegates().list("syl.guy@mydomain.com");
        List<Delegate> delegates = request2.execute().getDelegates();
        System.out.println(delegates.toString());
```

With this code above, I have the following result in the output console :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Delegation denied for inbound.admin@mydomain.com",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Delegation denied for inbound.admin@mydomain.com"
}
```

But, if a instanciate a Gmail object with a credential that impersonate the same user that the one I want to see/modify, it is working !
If a modify the line :

```java
GoogleCredential credential2 = addServiceAccountGoogleCredentialAndProxy(credential,"inbound.admin@mydomain.com");
```

by :

```java
GoogleCredential credential2 = addServiceAccountGoogleCredentialAndProxy(credential,"syl.guy@mydomain.com");
```

I have a result in the output console :

```
[{"delegateEmail":"elsa@mydomain.com","verificationStatus":"accepted"}]
```

The pb is that if I have 100 users to set up their delegates, I need to instanciate 100 GoogleCredential and Gmail object ? Can you confirm ?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), there's a great explanation on the topic as well as examples.

Comment: Thank you, I know this page. The example used Admin SDK API that can be used to create/modify users with the same impersonated user. The Gmail API seems to work differently as I need to impersonate the user that I want to modify (=connect as him => instantiate a new Credential + Gmail object). Could you confirm it?

Comment: You should follow [this example](https://ebstalimited.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017031473-How-to-a-create-Gmail-service-account). But in short, you can have the service account delegated, [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings) provides a good explanation.